# Joining associative arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have two arrays:

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [Date] => 2019-05-04 18:40:00
        [Item] => Prasanta Kumar Ray
        [Code] => 
        [Amount] => 150
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Date] => 2019-05-04 21:23:00
        [Item] => Dr Praveenkumar
        [Code] => 
        [Amount] => 150
    )

)
```

Second

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [Date] => 2019-05-04 18:45:00
        [Item] => TC DC ESR
        [Code] => 
        [Amount] => 60
    )
)
```

How to join them together to get an associative Array of length 3? thx in advance.

I tried array_merge and array_push. Didn't work.

Comment: What is the output you are expecting? Just a simple merge?

Comment: Yes. I have got the answer. I was adding unnecessary [] during array_merge. Now it works, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_merge` to merge them in a single `array`

```
$arr1 = Array
(
   '0' => Array
   (
    'Date' => '2019-05-04 18:40:00',
    'Item' => 'Prasanta Kumar Ray',
    'Code' => '',
    'Amount' => 150
   ),
  '1' => Array
   (
    'Date' => '2019-05-04 21:23:00',
    'Item' => 'Dr Praveenkumar',
    'Code' => '',
    'Amount' => 150
   )
);

$arr2 = Array
(
   '0' => Array
    (
     'Date' => '2019-05-04 18:45:00',
     'Item' => 'TC DC ESR',
     'Code' =>  '',
     'Amount' => 60
    )
);
$res = array_merge($arr1,$arr2);
```

Output

```
 Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Date] => 2019-05-04 18:40:00
        [Item] => Prasanta Kumar Ray
        [Code] => 
        [Amount] => 150
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Date] => 2019-05-04 21:23:00
        [Item] => Dr Praveenkumar
        [Code] => 
        [Amount] => 150
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Date] => 2019-05-04 18:45:00
        [Item] => TC DC ESR
        [Code] => 
        [Amount] => 60
    )

 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure?

> I tried **array_merge** and array_push. Didn't work.

Try with  `array_merge()` or `array_merge_recursive()`. Both should work for you.

```
<?php
$array1 = array
    (
    array
    (
        "Date" => "2019-05-04 18:40:00",
        "Item" => "Prasanta Kumar Ray",
        "Code" => null,
        "Amount" => 150
    )
    ,
    array
    (
        "Date" => "2019-05-04 21:23:00",
        "Item" => "Dr Praveenkumar",
        "Code" =>null ,
        "Amount" => 150
    )
);
$array2 = array
    (
    array
    (
        "Date" => "2019-05-04 18:45:00",
        "Item" => "TC DC ESR",
        "Code" => null,
        "Amount" => 60
    )
);
$array3 = array_merge_recursive($array1,$array2);
print_r($array3);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/E9Y1D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge and keep the array sorted on date then you need to use array_column to make the arrays associative on date, the ksort the array and reset the key with array_values.

```
$new = array_merge(array_column($arr1, null, 'Date'), array_column($arr2, null, 'Date'));

ksort($new);
$new = array_values($new);
var_dump($new);
```

Output of this:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Date"]=>
    string(19) "2019-05-04 18:40:00"
    ["Item"]=>
    string(18) "Prasanta Kumar Ray"
    ["Code"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Amount"]=>
    int(150)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Date"]=>
    string(19) "2019-05-04 18:45:00"
    ["Item"]=>
    string(9) "TC DC ESR"
    ["Code"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Amount"]=>
    int(60)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Date"]=>
    string(19) "2019-05-04 21:23:00"
    ["Item"]=>
    string(15) "Dr Praveenkumar"
    ["Code"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Amount"]=>
    int(150)
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/0lFF4